# What affect will upgrading from ASP.NET MVC2 to MVC3 have on NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

How do I upgrade ASP.NET MVC2 to MVC3 with minimal possible implications to NHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's there should be no impact in terms of NHibernate if you properly separated concerns in your application by using abstractions. As far as upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 application to ASP.NET MVC 3 application is concerned you could follow the [upgrading steps](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) mentioned in the release notes or even try the [Upgrade Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx).

Comment: The same happens on fluent-nhibernate?

Comment: @LuisHiluy, yeah sure, same. Works fine. Just upgrade your project and there won't be any problems with your DAL layer.